# cannot perform command after remote logging in via ssh

Tags: ssh, ros

I'm trying to use my Linux VM to ssh to a Drone (running Linux 16.4) and perform command `roscore` to start the Drone. The command is:

So I do, for example, `ssh drone@192.168.1.1 'roscore'`, and I actually got:

```
ngocdp@ngocdp-VirtualBox:~$ ssh drone@192.168.1.1 'uptime;bash'
drone@192.168.1.1's password: 
bash: roscore: command not found
```

If I just run ssh on my Terminal `ssh drone@192.168.1.1` and then manually run `roscore`, I can start it successfully:

```
ngocdp@ngocdp-VirtualBox:~$ ssh drone@192.168.1.1
drone@192.168.1.1's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-45-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

211 packages can be updated.
136 updates are security updates.

Last login: Sun Jul  7 17:04:59 2019 from 192.168.1.100
drone@drone-Drone:~$ roscore
WARNING: unable to configure logging. No log files will be generated
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
```

I would expect the command `ssh drone@192.168.1.1 'roscore'` would get into the root directory `drone@drone-Drone:~$` first, then execute the command `roscore`.

When I try `pwd`, by `ssh drone@192.168.1.1 'pwd'`, it give `home\drone`, which is the root directory. But I don't know why I cannot execute the command.

Comment: When you enter an interactive session (i.e. don't supply a specific command to be executed), ssh executes the remote user's *login shell*, which likely provides a different environment from that you get when you execute the command `roscore` directly (could be something as simple as a different `PATH` for example)

Comment: I had a few reads about the interactive session and it seems like it loads a different environment. Thus, I have to source the Ros setup up file prior to running `roscore`. So command look something like `ssh drone@192.168.1.1 'source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash;roscore'`. Then it can execute `roscore`. I'm not sure if there is a better way to do this, but so far it worked for me.

Comment: That sounds like it should be an answer - please consider posting it. You will be able to accept it yourself after a short while.